# How to read a file in a while loop that ends with special strings?

Tags: java, file

The code example here will be in Java, but I've encountered this problem in C++ and basically anywhere I have to parse such a file.  I'm working with parsing strings from a file that come from an electronic design automation software suite.  The file is called a "netlist", and it contains information regarding the electronic devices as well as special strings.  Here is a sample:

```
R3 1 4 137 425 1
R4 1 2 60 479 0
R5 2 3 55 596 0
V2 3 4 171 680 1
.end
```

I have a Java class, `Device`, which takes in a line of the file and inputs the data into member variables for each device (for instance, the top line is a resistor called R3, connected to nodes 1 and 4 etc).  When I get to the .end string, which comes from the EDA software, I obviously cannot parse it into a Device.

I feel like I keep re-writing the same code over and over, and it feels like a serious anti-pattern to me.  I use a while loop to read each line, check if it isn't the ".end" string, and then check that *again* as the condition to leave the loop:

```
String line = "";
         BufferedReader in;

         in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
         while(line != null && !line.startsWith(".end"))
         {
                line = in.readLine();
                //this feels like an anti-pattern...
                if(!line.startsWith("end"))
                {
                    Device d = new Device();
                    d.parseDeviceData(line);
                    devices.add(d); //devices  is an ArrayList
                }
         }
```

It's that double check that bothers me.  The only way around it that I can think of is to read the first line outside of the while loop, then read each line at  the end of the loop, but that doesn't really solve my problem.  Why should I have two readLine statements?

So, am I right to think this is an anti-pattern?   If so, how do I avoid it?

Comment: try using ```break;``` ?

Comment: as an aside, you could also create a constructor for the device that takes the data directly, instead of creating then parsing.

Comment: Note that files should now be read with javas new I/O library **NIO**, there you use the classes `Files` and `Paths`. They also offer **line-wise streams**.

Comment: @Zabuza: would using NIO solve this problem?

Comment: No, it is just a note. **NIO** is more stable than the old API and easier to read (imo). There you could also just use `Files.lines("filename")` which returns a `Stream<String>`. However a `Stream` is probably not the best option for "*read until*". However you can retrieve an `Iterator` of it and then use your logic pattern again, the method is `Stream#iterator`. Note that **Java 9** adds methods `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` to `Stream`s, there no conversion will be necessary.

Comment: Hm, I see I'm a bit out of date (I learned Java back in 2004 and have been using it for smalll projects ever since).  I'll take a look at updating myself

Comment: "antipattern" feeling is only on personal wish, to be too orthodox. I guess university way of thinking while {} is better than for(;;) { if ... break; }

Comment: @JacekCz: I am indeed at a university, interestingly enough, and we do teach students to avoid the `for(;;)...` method of doing things.   Out of curiosity, why would I use that over a while loop?

Comment: There is no better or worst theoretical loop, but natural expression to algorithm.  for(;;) is not +/- over while(true), maybe university teach kind of , but I cant understad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to read a file line-wise and stop if either reached the end or if a line that starts with `.end` occurred. Your current approach can indeed be simplified because the result of the second check is already known.

Here is how I would do it:

```
BufferedReader in;
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

while (true) {
    String line = in.readLine();
    if (line == null || line.startsWith(".end")) {
        // Abort parsing the file
        break;
    }

    // Valid line, parse it
    Device d = new Device();
    d.parseDeviceData(line);
    devices.add(d);
}
```

If you do not like the `while (true)` then you could also save the result of the comparison inside a **variable**.

---

Note that we should now use Javas new I/O library called **NIO**. It is more robust, easier to use and has more to offer. Its main classes are `Files` and `Paths`. Of special interest are `Files#readAllLines` and `Files#lines`, the first returns a `List<String>` holding the complete content of the file, the second one returns a `Stream<String>` where you can then unfold the full capability of *Lambda expressions*.

Note that, currently, both methods are not the best options to implement a *"read until"* because the first will read the whole content and `Stream`s are also not easy to *abort*. Therefore **Java 9** will introduce methods `Stream#takeWhile` and `Stream#dropWhile`.

However `Stream`s can easily be transformed into `Iterator`s and they can again be used with *regular logic*, so we could use this code instead:

```
Iterator<String> lineIterator = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).iterator();

while (lineIterator.hasNext()) {
    String line = lineIterator.next();
    if (line.startsWith(".end")) {
        // Abort parsing the file
        break;
    }

    // Valid line, parse it
    Device d = new Device();
    d.parseDeviceData(line);
    devices.add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your line scanning bit into the while condition:

```
while(!(line = in.readLine()).startsWith(".end"))
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

It's not nice looking but it will prevent you from having to test your condition twice. It will become dirtier(really dirty!) if you have many conditions to check though.

Comment: Will break at null. Elegant but not in reality

Comment: @JacekCz Although he "should" never have to deal with null if he is absolutely sure that his files will always finish with ".end". But I agree that he should not rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but answer seems seems extremely simply

```
     String line = null;
     BufferedReader in;

     in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
     for(;;)
     // instead use while(true) on personal taste / teacher / tradition / :)
     {
            line = in.readLine();
            if(line == null)
            {
                 // break because of eof, wrong end, do something !!!!
                 // throw new XxxxxxxxException("bad end of file")  
                 break;

            }  
            if( line.startsWith(".end") )
            {  
               // correnct end
                break;
            }
            Device d = new Device();
            d.parseDeviceData(line);
            devices.add(d); //devices  is an ArrayList

     }
```

Comment: `for(;;)` is the same as `while (true)` and in my opinion the later is far more easy to *read*. The logic of your two `if-branches` is the same, you could avoid the code duplication by combining the `boolean expressions` with a **logical or** like `if (line == null || line.startsWith("end"))`. But in general you are right, the `break` works and probably solves the issue.

Comment: TWO break, to be important. Both break's are not the same, one is failure, one is normal

Comment: Depends on the view I guess because at some point the end of the file will be reached, in all regular executions. And `readLine` indicates this by returning `null`. But I get your point, it could be possible that OP wants to handle the cases differently.